# is creating serializer mandatory for each View in django rest frame work

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am working on app where I didnt use serializer in one view I just want to ask am I doing something wrong.
I am getting a committee id in the url and in the body I am getting the usr_id whos status I want to change if someone sends a post request to this end point.
This is my url

```
path('committee/<int:id>/accept-request/', RequestAcceptView.as_view(), name="accept-request"),
```

this is my view.py

```
class RequestAcceptView(APIView):
def post(self, request, id): 
        user_id = request.data['user']
        print("iddddd",user_id )
        try :
            approve_request = Member.objects.filter(
                Q (com=Committee.objects.get(id=id)) 
            ).update(mem_status="fully_approved")
            return Response(SuccessResponse(msg="Request accepted"))
        except:
            return Response(ErrorResponse(msg="invalid))
```

I want to know I am not using serializer here for any purpose, is it fine? should I remove serializer file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not when you are using ApiView. Generic and ModelView requires them. You should also think about if you want to have auto generated documentation you need the serializer and it will also perform validation (because you are not using the id field, but request.data.
If request.data and I'd are the same, then you might want to delete the serializer

Comment: oh you cleared my doubts , but I have created some serializers when I am returning qurerysets so that I can serialized them even tho i was using APIVIEW. is it fine?

Comment: Yes. It's just that you won't benefit of some tools like generate openapi spec from django or drfspectacular (or anything that depend on a serializer for introspection.
But internally, GenericViews and model serializer will do almost what you did :
`get_queryset(), get_serializer(), perform_operation, then return a response according to the response with the data serializer through the serializer.